# Reading a `BLOB` via JDBC takes too long

Tags: java, blob

When I read an image from database, it appears in the `JLabel` immediately, but it takes too much time to complete streaming the `BLOB` from the DB.

```
public byte[] selectImage(int Id) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet res=null;
    int c=0;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(con.getAutoCommit());

    statement = con.createStatement() ;
    res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT PHOTO FROM CUSTOMER where ID="+Id) ;

    while(res.next() && (res!=null)) {
        Blob bodyOut = res.getBlob("PHOTO");
        int length = (int) bodyOut.length();
        System.out.println("   Body Size = "+length);
        imageBytes = bodyOut.getBytes(1, length);
        bodyOut.free(); 
    }

    return imageBytes;
}
```

Comment: It's almost like you shouldn't store image data in a database - just a reference to the file on disk. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Consider storing the image outside of the database. Only store enough info in the DB to let you find the file (either on the filesystem, or from an HTTP server, or however you're storing it now that it's not in the DB). Binary data isn't really the use case that an RDBMS is optimized to handle.

Also, your code has some serious problems:

1. The biggest problem is probably the security flaw you get by failing to use bind variables, a.k.a. a [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in Java. This is SQL injection 101.
2. you're using raw JDBC. Raw JDBC is tedious and easy to mess up. For instance, you aren't closing your `ResultSet` or your `Connection`, not to mention the `statement` variable, which should definitely be local. And when you do start closing them, you should do it in a `finally` block to make sure it always happens, even if there is an error.
3. If you happen to get more than one result from your query—I'm guessing you shouldn't, but just in case—you will only know if you happen to look at `STDOUT`, and you'll just get the last image. Your `while` loop is probably better expressed as an `if` to indicate that you only expect and/or care about the first result. If you care if there is more than one results, you should probably use an `if` instead of a while, then add a subsequent `if (rs.next()) throw new MyAppropriatelyNamedException;` so you know that there is something unexpected going on.
4. The `null` check for `res` is worthless. By the time you execute the check, the `rs.next()` statement will have already thrown a `NullPointerException`. You should probably just delete the check.
5. Why are you using the logging framework, only to turn around and use `System.out.println` to output some debugging info?

Comment: Storing BLOBs in the database might sometimes even be faster depending on the images and the access pattern. Read this interesting article: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525 (SQL Server related but I wouldn't be surprised if this is valid for other DBMS just as well)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As always, every situation has its own unique nuances, but putting binary data in your DB should be the carefully justified exception to the general rule: don't put binary data in a RDBMS.

Comment: personally I have good experience with putting BLOBs into the database. It makes life so much easier (no file-system cleanups, no permission problems, a single DB backup contains everything, storing them is transaction safe, no worries about distributing 1.000.000 files over a directory hierarchy). But I agree that with large images it puts an unnecessary burden on the DB. But then, modern DBMS can really handle this very well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I said, every situation is different. In my case, it makes no sense to put files in a database, because they're going to be served by a webserver. If the webserver is already optimized for serving files, why waste resources putting stuff in a DB and looking it up? Also, you often-times wind up treating binary resources differently than regular data in your DB anyway: separate tablespaces, different backup strategies, etc. It's probably better to let the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay cover the details.

Comment: I completely agree - especially regarding *every situation is different* ;)